# Clean comment.cut file with latexmk

Tags: latexmk, cleanup

`latexmk -C` does not remove the temporary auxiliary `comment.cut` file created by the `comment` package. How can this functionality be achieved?

MWE:

```
$ latexmk --version

Latexmk, John Collins, 25 October 2018. Version 4.61

$ cat test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\specialcomment{smalltt}{\begingroup}{\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\begin{smalltt}
test
\end{smalltt}
\end{document}

$ latexmk && latexmk -C
[...]

$ ls
comment.cut  test.tex
```

Setting `$clean_full_ext='cut';` in `~/.latexmkrc` does not work:

```
$ cat ~/.latexmkrc
$clean_full_ext='cut';

$ ls
test.tex

$ (latexmk && latexmk -C) &> /dev/null && ls
comment.cut  test.tex
```

I tried other extensions and they seem to work fine:

```
$ cat ~/.latexmkrc
$clean_full_ext='jpg'

$ echo abc > test.jpg && ls
test.jpg  test.tex

$ (latexmk && latexmk -C) &> /dev/null && ls
comment.cut  test.tex
```

Comment: Add `$clean_full_ext='cut';` to the `.latexmkrc` file

Comment: @user185617 Interestingly, this does not work `$ rm -f comment.cut && cat ~/.latexmkrc
$clean_full_ext='cut';
$ latexmk &> /dev/null && latexmk -C && ls
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 25 October 2018, version: 4.61.
comment.cut  test.tex`.
I tried other extensions and they seem to work fine.

Comment: @MiBr your last comment is not very clear as to what is commands and what is output, could you update your question with that information instead?

Comment: Note that AFAIK latexmk only cleans files that has the same base name as the document being worked on. `comment.cut` does not share the basename

Comment: @daleif I updated my question. But you're right, the  `jpg` extension test only works because i call the file `test.jpg`, otherwise `latexmk` does not attempt deletion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Latexmk maintainer here:  What you have found is the actual situation in the current version of `latexmk`.  Originally the `$clean_full_ext` variable was to specify **extensions** of the files to be deleted in a cleanup, with the base name being the same as that of the .tex file.  I extended it to allow more general patterns, with wildcards, but with a requirement that the pattern contain the placeholder `%R`, which gets replaced by the base name of the .tex file.  That was needed in practice.

But I felt nervous about a more general wildcarding pattern, since a minor error in configuration could have rather dangerous consequences.  Even so, it would be useful to have a way of deleting specific files like `comment.cut`.  I'll take this as a feature request.

Meanwhile, the easiest way to solve your problem is simply to configure things so that the comment file does not have a fixed name, but is the base name of the .tex file followed by the extension `.cut`.  This can be done by putting

```
\def\DefaultCutFileName{\def\CommentCutFile{\jobname.cut}}
\DefaultCutFileName
```

in the preamble of your document, and then setting

```
$clean_full_ext = 'cut';
```

in a `.latexmkrc` file.  Better is to do

```
$clean_ext .= ' cut';
```

which appends one item and so does not undo previous settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Couldn't `latexmk` use the information in the `.fls` file for cleanups? It lists `comment.cut` as an output of the compilation process in my case. Seems like a pretty fail-safe way to do more complete cleanups or am I missing something?